# Disable permanent active state

Tags: javascript, css

I have a link, and if you drag this link then release, the link will keep his active state.

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/Ek43k/3/

```
<a href="javascript:void(0);" id="foo" >Drag me</a>
```

```
#foo:active{
    color:red;
}
```

How can I prevent this?

(Only in IE and FF)

Comment: I can't reproduce that problem you describe. The link colour reverts to blue after it has slide back into position.

Comment: This appears to happen in FireFox and IE But not Chrome.

Comment: i guess you can't because before you drag the link per  default you click on it and when you click on it it will get the active css class so i guess their is no solution for that

Comment: @Quentin IE has the problem I tried.

Comment: @Sora — The active state *should* be lost when the button is released.

Comment: I don't think it's possible to have a pure css solution. CSS includes no primitives that I'm aware of that can be combined to alter/control the 'activeness' of a link.

Comment: you should use javascript or jquery to detect the dragging event of the mouse than i guess wld be a good solution

Comment: check this link it may be useful :
http://help.dottoro.com/ljsluknm.php

Comment: @Sora Why read a third-party document when the browser vendor has such a complete and well-organized documentation site of their own? It seems counter-intuitive to ask someone else when you can get the info straight from the browser's mouth, so to speak. This should be your reference: https://developer.mozilla.org

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Detach and reattach the link from the DOM tree to disable its active state. Do this when the drag ends and you've [got this](http://jsfiddle.net/Ek43k/86/):

```
$('a').on('dragend',function(){
    var $this   = $(this),
        $parent = $this.parent(),
        $next   = $(this.nextSibling); // $.next() doesn't include text
    $this.detach().insertBefore($next);     
});
```

No need to mess with your HTML or CSS or do away with `:active`. Seems to work in both FF and IE.

---

**Edit:** I don't usually write pure Javascript for DOM-handling so the quality of this might not be top notch, but [here it is without jQuery](http://jsfiddle.net/Ek43k/83/):

```
(function(){
    var previousOnload = window.onload || function noop(){};

    window.onload = function (){

        // Call any previously added onload callbacks
        previousOnload();

        // Add deactivator to each <a> element
        var elements = document.getElementsByTagName('a');
        for (var i=0; i<elements.length; i++){
            elements[i].ondragend = deactivate;
        }

        function deactivate(){
            var parent   = this.parentNode,
                position = this.nextSibling;
            parent.removeChild(this);
            // Using insertBefore instead of appendChild so that it is put at the right position among the siblings
            parent.insertBefore(this, position);
        }
    };

})();
```

I took care of a few issues that came to mind to make it fully plug-and-play. Tested in Opera, Chrome, Firefox and Internet Explorer.

---

**Edit 2:** Inspired by Chris, another way to apply the fix is to use the `ondragend` attribute directly to connect the `deactivator` (not tested):

```
<head>
    <script>
        function deactivate(){
            var parent   = this.parentNode,
                position = this.nextSibling;
            parent.removeChild(this);
            // Using insertBefore instead of appendChild so that it is put at the right position among the siblings
            parent.insertBefore(this, position);
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <a href="#" ondragend="deactivate()">Drag me</a>
<body>
```

The downside is that it requires the `ondragend` attribute with javascript to be specified on each link manually/explicitly. I guess it's a matter of preference.

---

**Final (?) Edit:** See comments for delegate/live versions of these and Chris' answer.

Comment: The really good thing is that I don't need to change my CSS (just to add this code) but you should write it in pure JS because there isn't the `jQuery` tag.

Comment: That seems like a lot of code (and assumptions about existing `body.onload` and `element.ondragend` events) just to avoid a little CSS class -- remember, this is a temporary problem.

Comment: "A little CSS class" still requires Javascript to maintain it. Your workaround inlines the Javascript, but if you want to apply it to all links then you would still need something like what I'm doing. The only difference is that `deactivate` would be adding and removing a class instead of the element itself. My code is not assuming anything about onload, that's why it's a bit longer. You could even yank out all the onload stuff if you are willing to put the core of the script at the end of the document.

Comment: And on the topic of assumptions, what happens in your code if the link is supposed to have another class on it as well for other purposes? Any existing classes will be lost, will they not? In what sense is this a temporary problem? You said yourself to not hold our breaths for a bugfix ;)

Comment: LOL, you went inline, I went delegate :p http://jsfiddle.net/ymPfH/ <-- your approach, leaner code, http://jsfiddle.net/HYJCQ/ <-- my approach, leaner code

Comment: Yeah :P That's nice when elements may be added dynamically. You're clearly more comfortable with pure Javascript than me. Special cases like IE is precisely the reason I prefer jQuery. For completeness, here's the delegate version of the jQuery version: http://jsfiddle.net/Ek43k/85/

Comment: +1 to the answer! You should put that jsFiddle in your answer too. Lol there is no aspect of this question that has not been addressed now -- cause, multiple work-arounds, jQuery, yep... we've got it all.

Comment: And imagine all this work is simply to deal with a minor visual glitch which most people won't even notice... :P

Answer (score 7):

This is a known bug in Firefox, see https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=193321

The bug has had an on-and-off status with several reports; the behavior is non-standard and browser-specific.

You **can** build a work-around for it, but you're stuck with javascript. After much searching, I determined that unless you're running in privileged mode (i.e. your code is in an extension), you cannot directly influence the pseudo-selector states. That means you're left with adding/removing a class name:

```
<a href="#" onmousedown="this.className = '';" ondragend="this.className = 'inactive';" id="foo" >Drag me</a>
```

Try it: http://jsfiddle.net/frsRS/

If you **do** have privileged mode, you can use the method that Firebug employs in their CSS Panel, using `inIDOMUtils.setContentState`

```
var node = document.getElementById("foo");
var domUtil = Components.classes["@mozilla.org/inspector/dom-utils;1"].getService(Components.interfaces.inIDOMUtils);
domUtil.setContentState( node , 1);
```

**Edit**

Here is specific code for binding cross-browser delegates rather than putting the javascript inline (shown here for demonstration purposes, but generally bad practice)

```
function addEvent(ele, evnt, funct) {
  if (ele.addEventListener) // W3C
    return ele.addEventListener(evnt,funct,false);
  else if (ele.attachEvent)  // IE
    return ele.attachEvent("on"+evnt,funct);
}
addEvent(document.body, 'mousedown', function (e) {        
    if(e.target.tagName == 'A') e.target.style.color = '';

});
addEvent(document.body, 'dragend', function (e) {
    if(e.target.tagName == 'A') e.target.style.color = 'blue';
});
```

Try it: http://jsfiddle.net/HYJCQ/

This uses the element's style rather than a css class, you can swap out the methods as desired.

Another way, as suggested by Supr, is to remove and immediately re-add the element from DOM. You can accomplish this using a delegate as well:

```
function addEvent(ele, evnt, funct) {
  if (ele.addEventListener) // W3C
    return ele.addEventListener(evnt,funct,false);
  else if (ele.attachEvent)  // IE
    return ele.attachEvent("on"+evnt,funct);
}
addEvent(document.body, 'dragend', function (e) {
    if(e.target.tagName != 'A') return;
    var parent = e.target.parentNode;
    var sib = e.target.nextSibling;
    parent.insertBefore(
        parent.removeChild(e.target),
        sib
    );
});
```

Try it: http://jsfiddle.net/ymPfH/

Both methods that utilize delegation are better approaches than looping elements -- that way, the script will apply to any `a` tags added to the page after load (similar to how jQuery's `live` or `on` methods work).

**Documentation**

- Bugzilla entry - https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=193321
- Drag and Drop on MDN (`ondragend`) - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Drag_and_Drop
- `inIDOMUtils` - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/XPCOM_Interface_Reference/inIDOMUtils

Comment: Very good! I'll just wait 4 or 5 days. (PS: The css of `:active` must be before `.inactive` to work).

Comment: I wouldn't hold your breath for a bugfix -- it has been active since 2009, and keeps getting re-introduced. Vote for the bug on bugzilla to help, but it doesn't seem to be a very high priority. As far as the order of the css... the jsFiddle works as-is for my version (14.0.1)

Answer (score -1):

If jQuery is an option, I think this code works, at least in FF: http://jsfiddle.net/Ek43k/89/

HTML

```
<a href="#" id="foo" class="inactive" >Drag me</a>
```

CSS

```
.inactive:active{color:red;}
.active:active{color:blue;}
```

jQuery

```
$('body').on('mousedown', 'a.inactive', function() {
    $(this).on('mousemove', function() {
        $(this).removeClass().addClass('active');
    });
});

$('body').on('mousedown', 'a.active', function() {
    $(this).removeClass().addClass('inactive');
});
```

Answer (score -3):

just add this CSS:

```css
#foo:hover {
    color: green;
}
```

Comment: -1 Did you test this? It does not address the stated problem at all